# Word meaning 'The seeking out and assimilation of information.'

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives, gerunds

Such as the hungering after of knowledge, but in a singular word. My thanks.

Comment: The SWR tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Comment: I would say "learning".  Or "education".

Comment: Why do you need a single word?  You have not provided a sample sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ***[epistemophilia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistemophilia)*** is close to what you are referring to:

> - love of knowledge; specifically :  excessive striving for or preoccupation with knowledge.

(M-W)